# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in python code which uses google API

Tags: python, json

i have this code which searches for a word in google using google API, but for once it works fine but if i add many words or if i run it many times i keep getting the following error...

```
    results = jsonResponse['responseData']['results']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

i tried searching a lot on google but couldnt know what the issue is.. can anyone please help me knowing the issue and how to handle it... was struggling with this error

```
 import urllib
    import urllib2
    from urllib import urlencode
    import json as m_json
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    import re
    import json
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    import sys
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    import urllib2
    import simplejson
    import pprint

    words = ['headache','diabetes','myopia','dhaed','snow','blindness','head','ache','acne','aids','blindness','head','ache','acne','aids','blindness','head','ache','acne','aids']


    for word in words:
     url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web'
           '?v=1.0&q='+word+'&userip=192.168.1.105')
     request = urllib2.Request(url)
     response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
     jsonResponse=json.loads(response.read())
     #print "the response now is: ",jsonResponse
     #pprint.pprint(jsonResponse)
     results = jsonResponse['responseData']['results']
     for result in results:
      print "\nthe result is: ",result
      url =result['url']
      print "\nthe url is: ",url
      try:
       page=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
      except urllib2.HTTPError,err:
       if err.code == 403:
        print "bad"
        continue
       else:
        print "good"
        break
      except urllib2.HTTPError:
        print "server error"
      except:
       print "dont know the error"
```

thanks is advance..

Comment: Please format the code in your question properly. Copy-paste it as-is; then select the code, and press the `{}` button on the toolbar; alternatively, press `ctrl`+`K`. Now everyone would just get a `SyntaxError` from a copy-paste.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that when there are no results, `jsonResponse['responseData']` is `None` so it has no *property* named `results` in the results or `responseData` itself is `None` (== JSON `null`). (The dictionary lookup fails, either for `jsonResponse` or `jsonResponse['responseData']` being null/None.

Dump the output when that error happens to see which is `None` and then add a check for it before the line `results = jsonResponse['responseData']['results']`.

Comment: how do i dump the output?/ i only have some knowledge in pythion.. can you suggest me one.. will be trying till then

Comment: In your case, maybe something simple like `print jsonResponse` after `jsonResponse=json.loads(response.read())`, or if you can do it on the interpreter by just entering `jsonResponse`. In the log run, consider using the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html). This print/dump is temporary, just to see the cause of the error/details of the data so you can add the relevant check to your code.

Comment: i added  

 if jsonResponse['responseData'] is not None:
 
 results = jsonResponse['responseData']['results']

and else at the last.. the word which i wanted to searched gets skipped when i use this.. is there any way to go back and search for the same word again? like goto or label??.. thanks for the reply

Comment: Instead of writing one long program, break it down into bits with functions which you will call. Like `def search(word): ...` with the basic search you do. Then loop the results of each, etc. Searching for a missing word will usually give you no results even the second time you search, so not sure what you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

[Aneroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431750/aneroid)
 is correct about the response data.

One possible solution to handle this:

```
responseData = jsonResponse['responseData']
if responseData is not None:
    results = responseData['results']
    for results in results:
        # your code
else:
    print "No Response"
```